# Display PHP Errors on Serverpilot

Tags: php

I'm trying to upgrade my site from php5.6/mysql, to php7.0/mysqli.
Currently I'm hosted to digitalocean with serverpilot.io, but I can't find a way to display php errors, it just display white page after i change to php 7.0.
Tried this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

but same result.

Comment: I don't know Serverpilot, but do you don't have an option in the console/panel to show PHP errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in the public folder .user.ini add add

display_errors = On

Or run this in the terminal in the public directory

```
$ echo 'display_errors = On' > .user.ini
```

see https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-change-php-settings.html